# unable to start WAS deployment manager after proper installation

Tags: websphere, server, wsrr

I have successfully installed WAS deployment manager using below script:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/bin/manageprofiles.sh -response /opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/WSRR/install/profile-responsefiles/create-dmgr.txt
```

But when I try to start deployment manager:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/bin# /opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/profiles/dmgr/bin/startManager.sh
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/profiles/dmgr/logs/dmgr/startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the dmgr profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: dmgr
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs,
           startServer.log, and other log files under
           /opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/profiles/dmgr/logs/dmgr should
           contain failure information.
```

log file I get:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/ServiceRegistry/profiles/dmgr/logs/dmgr# tail SystemOut.log
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:380)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:151)

[4/12/15 15:10:04:272 PDT] 00000001 CGBridgeServi I   CWRCB0103I: The core group bridge service has stopped.
[4/12/15 15:10:04:276 PDT] 00000001 DragDropDeplo I   CWLDD0004I: Stopping monitored directory application deployment service... 
[4/12/15 15:10:04:280 PDT] 00000001 DragDropDeplo I   CWLDD0005I: Monitored directory application deployment service is stopped. 
[4/12/15 15:10:04:287 PDT] 00000001 CfwTCPListene I   ODCF8525I: The unstructured overlay is stopping its inbound TCP channel.
```

Comment: You pasted a partial stack trace and a few unrelated INFO messages.  Please update with the full error message.

Comment: I've update with entire exception list

Comment: You still didn't provide the full stack trace. Stop the server, remove SystemOut.log, then start the server, `open` SystemOut.log and try to look for the first exceptions, paste here just the last few lines using `tail`. Also to also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter`, see the help link just under `Add Comment` button.